# How to sort values on ngx-chart-line-chart tooltip

Tags: angular, linechart, ngx-charts

Here is a line-chart example https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/line-chart.

If you hover on that you'll see a tooltip:

[image]

As you can see the values on tooltip is not sorted. Is there anyway to make the tooltip values sorted at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

You can sort the data like:

```
this.data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0;
});
```

**<kbd>[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lj6unq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)</kbd>**